# Library Project - How to Pull an Object from an Array and Display it on HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

Im building a small Library App/Project. I have a form that when you enter in a "Book Title" the javascript searches through the Array of object with a match and then Displays all of the Books info to the HTML "Library Card"

However it isnt working, but I think my logic is good. Can you help me?

This is the "Library Card" and the "Find Book Form"

```js
let libraryArray = [{
    AUTHOR: 'WILLIAM GOLDING',
    TITLE: 'LORD OF THE FLIES',
    PAGES: '224',
    READSTATUS: 'READ'
  },
  {
    AUTHOR: 'CS LEWIS',
    TITLE: 'THE HOBBIT',
    PAGES: '330',
    READSTATUS: 'UNREAD'
  },
  {
    AUTHOR: 'JK',
    TITLE: 'HARRY POTTER ',
    PAGES: '450',
    READSTATUS: 'READ'
  }
];

document.querySelector('#findButton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  const bookInput = document.querySelectorAll('.bookTitle')
  for (let i = 0; i < libraryArray.length; i++) {
    if (libraryArray[i].TITLE == bookInput[i].value) {
      document.getElementById("Author").innerHTML = libraryArray[i].AUTHOR;
      document.getElementById("Title").innerHTML = libraryArray[i].TITLE;
      document.getElementById("numPages").innerHTML = libraryArray[i].PAGES;
      document.getElementById("readStatus").innerHTML = libraryArray[i].READSTATUS;
    }
  }

  event.preventDefault();
}, false)
```

```html
<!--Libray card-->

<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-4 my-4">
        <div class="card mx-auto library-card text-center p-5">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="small card-text"> Copyrighted Material
              <p>
                <h3 class="card-title text-uppercase display-6">Library Card</h3>
                <div class="">_________________________</div>
                <div class="underline-space mb-3"></div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                  <li class="list-group-item text-uppercase mb-3" id="Author"></li>
                  <li class="list-group-item text-uppercase mb-3" id="Title"></li>
                  <li class="list-group-item text-uppercase mb-3">Number of Pages
                    <p class="numPages" id="numPages"></p>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item text-uppercase mb-3 readStatus">Read Status
                    <p class=" text-uppercase readStatus bg-white" id="readStatus"></p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end of Library Card-->

      <!--Find a Book form -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <form class="text-center bg-light p-5 rounded my-4 mx-auto addAuthor" id="findAuthor">
          <div class="form-group mx-auto">
            <h3 class="card-title text-uppercase display-6">Find a Book</h3>
            <div class="mb-4">___________________________</div>

            <input class="form-control text-uppercase mb-4 bookTitle" type="text" placeholder="Title" name="TITLE" value="">
            <br>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg rounded-pill px-5" id="findButton">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: One problem I can see is that when you're iterating through the array of books, you also indexing `bookInput`. There's only one element with the `bookTitle` class, so you need to change it to: 
`libraryArray[i].TITLE == bookInput[0].value`

Comment: @tromgy  that was right! Works like a charm. thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `bookInput[i].value` to `bookInput[0].value`. You only have one class. You could use `querySelector` rather than `querySelectorAll` to make things easier to follow as you wouldn't need to include the `[0].

```
let libraryArray = [{
        AUTHOR: 'WILLIAM GOLDING',
        TITLE: 'LORD OF THE FLIES',
        PAGES: '224',
        READSTATUS: 'READ'
      },
      {
        AUTHOR: 'CS LEWIS', /* J. R. R. Tolkien */
        TITLE: 'THE HOBBIT',
        PAGES: '330',
        READSTATUS: 'UNREAD'
      },
      {
        AUTHOR: 'JK',
        TITLE: 'HARRY POTTER ',
        PAGES: '450',
        READSTATUS: 'READ'
      }
    ];
    
    document.querySelector('#findButton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    
      const bookInput = document.querySelectorAll('.bookTitle')
      for (let i = 0; i < libraryArray.length; i++) {
        if (libraryArray[i].TITLE == bookInput[0].value) {
          document.getElementById("Author").innerHTML = libraryArray[i].AUTHOR;
          document.getElementById("Title").innerHTML = libraryArray[i].TITLE;
          document.getElementById("numPages").innerHTML = libraryArray[i].PAGES;
          document.getElementById("readStatus").innerHTML = libraryArray[i].READSTATUS;
        }
      }
    
      event.preventDefault();
    }, false)
```

Comment: This worked, sorry it took me forever to give you the award